# How to align output from an excel file?

Tags: java, excel, text-alignment, aspose

```
    ''''Workbook wb = new Workbook("workbook.xlsx");
    WorksheetCollection collection = wb.getWorksheets();
    
    
    for (int worksheetIndex = 0; worksheetIndex < collection.getCount(); worksheetIndex++) {
        
        Worksheet worksheet = collection.get(worksheetIndex);
        System.out.println("People on Island: " + worksheet.getName());
        System.out.println();
        
        int rows = worksheet.getCells().getMaxDataRow();
        int cols = worksheet.getCells().getMaxDataColumn();
        Style st = wb.createStyle();
        
        for (int i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
            
        for (int j = 0; j <= cols; j++)  {
            
            System.out.print(worksheet.getCells().get(i, j).getValue() + "   ");
            
            
        }
            
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        }
        
    }
}''''
```

OUTPUT CURRENTLY:

People on Island: Sheet1

First Name    Last name    Gender    Country   Age   Date

Dulce   Bleoop   Female   Zimbabwe   43   2035-03-01T00:00:00

Sheeba   Loadlee   Female   Sketchawan   24   3040-04-03T00:00:00

Jello   Bamop   Male   Antarctica    32   2053-04-06T00:00:00

Barbara    Slack   Female   Scandalousia   70   3203-03-12T00:00:00

Comment: Can you explain with detail what exact problem are you facing? Feel free too to name the library you are using.

Comment: I second @AlfredoTostón. I do not understand your problem. According to  your code segment, you are simply browsing in each sheet (in the workbook) and retrieving cells data. Could you please elaborate a bit more and share your desired output? I can check it and assist you accordingly.
PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AmjadSahi  I want the output headings to line up with the results. Like the first column "First Name" lines up with the peoples first names, but then the rest of the columns are not aligned or spaced out correctly.

Comment: @AlfredoTostón  My output headings are not flush / properly aligned or spaced out. The First Name column is right but the rest of the columns are not aligned.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71517402/edit) to add information, perhaps a screen cap of the result you get and one of the result you want for us to compare would clarify things better

Comment: May be you could add tab spaces using the line:
System.out.print(worksheet.getCells().get(i, j).getValue() + "\t\t"); to align better a bit.

You should share your sample desired output or screenshots for reference.

Comment: @AmjadSahi    it changes the alignment but does not make the subjects aligned with headings

Comment: @PhilMeraska, you may share the Excel spreadsheet containing the data to evaluate it thoroughly.
By the way, to get efficient help you may also post your queries/issue on dedicated forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
//Code for reading data, not relevant for the solution
    String my_string= """
            People on Island: Sheet1

            FirstName LastName Gender Country Age Date

            Dulce Bleoop Female Zimbabwe 43 2035-03-01T00:00:00

            Sheeba Loadlee Female Sketchawan 24 3040-04-03T00:00:00

            Jello Bamop Male Antarctica 32 2053-04-06T00:00:00

            Barbara Slack Female Scandalousia 70 3203-03-12T00:00:00""";

    String[] split_string = my_string.split("\n\n");

    String[][] finalString = new String[split_string.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < split_string.length; i++) {
        finalString[i] = split_string[i].split(" ");
    }
//Relevant code below
    int spaceBetween = 25; //this variable decides the distance between each column
    for (int i = 0; i < finalString.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < finalString[i].length; j++)  {
            System.out.print(finalString[i][j]);
            for (int k = 0; k < spaceBetween-finalString[i][j].length(); k++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
```

The output is:

```
People                   on                       Island:                  Sheet1                   

FirstName                LastName                 Gender                   Country                  Age                      Date                     

Dulce                    Bleoop                   Female                   Zimbabwe                 43                       2035-03-01T00:00:00      

Sheeba                   Loadlee                  Female                   Sketchawan               24                       3040-04-03T00:00:00      

Jello                    Bamop                    Male                     Antarctica               32                       2053-04-06T00:00:00      

Barbara                  Slack                    Female                   Scandalousia             70                       3203-03-12T00:00:00
```

The Space between each column is decided by the variable spaceBetween.

In conclusion, you should be able to change the line
`System.out.print(worksheet.getCells().get(i, j).getValue() + "   ");`
to

```
val = worksheet.getCells().get(i, j).getValue();
System.out.print(val);
for (int k = 0; k < spaceBetween-val.lenght(); k++)
    System.out.print(" ");
```

where you choose a value for spaceBetween somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to align the output lines printed in console, you will have to loop over the fields two times. The first for getting whe length of each column and the second to print them correctly.

You can use a method that given a `String` pads it with whitespaces to the end:

```java
public static String alignLeft(String str, int width) {
    if (str.length() >= width) {
        return str;
    }
    return alignLeft(str + " ", width);
}
```

Then, given the values of each cell as a `String` in a bidimensional array `cells`, doing the following:

```java
int[] columnsWidths = new int[cells[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
        if (columnsWidths[j] < cells[i][j].length()) {
            columnsWidths[j] = cells[i][j].length();
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(alignLeft(cells[i][j], columnsWidths[j]) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using aspose, since you included the tag, you could use the export to array method:

```
....

int rows = worksheet.getCells().getMaxDataRow();
int cols = worksheet.getCells().getMaxDataColumn();

Object dataTable[][] = worksheet.getCells().exportArray(0, 0, rows, cols);

for (final Object[] row : dataTable) {
    System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%n", row);
}
```

For left-aligned output change the print statement to

```
 System.out.format("%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%-15s%n", row);
```

Of course `15` is just a random value I choosed, because I thought the max length of a cell value has 15 chars. change as you see fit. You could also for each column, check length of all strings in that column and take max string length in that column as column width for that column. Which could end for example in something like:

```
System.out.format("%-10s%-10s%-8s%-15s%-5s%-25s%n", row);
```

Comment: This works up until I put the sixth "%15s" to get the Date output on the end. It gives me an Exception in thread "main" error for the "%15s" specifier. Otherwise this worked great!

Comment: @PhilMeraska Were you able to fix it? If not please share the error message.

Comment: @PhilMeraska If the error is related to that the last column is a date and not a string, just replace the last `%15s` with `%tF`

Comment: Strangely not the error since the column before the date is "Age", which outputs just fine. Still working on the issue. The error highlights Age exception in thread "main" java util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%-15s"

Comment: You may also check for blank cells in your sheet, which are possibly are exported as null. You may also change the for-each loop to a classic for loop `for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.length; i++) { System.out.format("%15s%15s%15s%15s%15s%tF%n", row);` starting from row `1` skiping the header.

Comment: This did not solve my problem. I just realized that the last row is also missing as well as the last column, "Date". I've been trying lots of things I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm a beginner software developer at my job so I'm still learning. This is just practice with Aspose to learn.